# django-haystack: how to access the spelling suggestions on the template?

Tags: python, django, solr, django-haystack

I'm trying django-haystack with Solr and `HAYSTACK_INCLUDE_SPELLING = True`.

How do you access the spelling suggestions on the template (generated by the default `SearchView`) ?

Edit: another question: Can the Spelling Suggestion find words from the database ? For example, using the default `Note` model from the haystack doc, and the default `SearchView`, there is no spelling suggestions when I search the word "Lorm" when the database contains a note called "Lorem ipsum". Is it normal ?

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have the search query set in the template, you can do:

```
{{ sqs.spelling_suggestion }}
```

Look at:
    http://docs.haystacksearch.org/dev/searchqueryset_api.html#spelling-suggestion

for more details.

For haystack to find the spelling suggestions, the search template should include the field you are looking for. So if you search template includes {{ object.title }}  you should be picking up the spelling suggestion.

Maybe you forgot to do

```
python manage.py update_index
```

after you added the lorem note.

Comment: I forgot to update the indexes. It's now working, thank you. :-)

Comment: Make sure that you don't have any additional filtering in sqs. sqs.filter(permission=True), for instance will return results that you didn't expect. Only the query in which suggestion is desired should be used. For example:

      query = request.GET.get('q', '') /
      sqs = SearchQuerySet().filter(content=AutoQuery(query)) /
      suggestion = sqs.spelling_suggestion() /

Answer (score 1):

`{{ suggestion }}` should suffice if you are using the default `SearchView`.

See:

https://github.com/toastdriven/django-haystack/blob/master/haystack/views.py#L118

...to see what is available in the template context.

Hassan is correct in stating that you must update/rebuild your index and that you need the right fields in your search template.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the above mentioned solutions only work if we are extending the `haystack.views.SearchView`. The new generic views based SearchView i.e `haystack.generic_views.SearchView` do not seem to be adding the  `suggestion` field to the context and we will not be able to access this context variable `{{ suggestion }}`.

We will need to manually add it to the context as follows:

```
from haystack.generic_views import SearchView

# Custom view.
class MySearchView(SearchView):

    template_name = 'search/search.html'
    queryset = SearchQuerySet().all()
    form_class = SearchForm  

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(MySearchView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)

        # Add any additional context data we need to display in forms
        spell_suggestion = self.get_form().get_suggestion()
        context['spell_suggestion'] = spell_suggestion

        return context
```

Add the view to urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('search/', MySearchView.as_view(), name='haystack_search'),
```

And then in the `search.html` access the context variable as `{{ spell_suggestion }}`

Hope this helps :)

Reference: https://django-haystack.readthedocs.io/en/v2.4.1/views_and_forms.html#upgrading